# How do you highlight the string in a quote on Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I recently found out that Notepad++ has a "Create Your User Defined Language" option. Now I use Notepad++ for mostly everything and I have been creating keywords, operators, comments all that stuff and everything works except for `""`. The quotes itself has syntax coloring but whenever I type something inside like `"Hello World!"`, The text inside does not have the syntax coloring. How do you add syntax on a text inside the quotes(`""`)?

Answer (score 1):

### You can add this functionality by doing the following:

In the main menu bar click Language > User Defined Language > Define your language...

Select your custom language from the user language dropdown menu

Click the Operators & Delimiters tab

In a Delimiter style box, enter " for both Open and Close

Click Styler and choose your font, fontsize, foreground, background color, etc.

Comment: ok thx. i really appreciate it.